# Angularjs - show/ hide table row on check of radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

So, My problem is I have a table which renders from an Array of objects, Firstly, rows with data loads which has nested rows. On user selection of any row - another nested row should load and all the other should be hidden. For example: At first - Name, custId, mobile is loaded for 3 users when a user selects the 1st row another row with different info should be shown while 2nd and 3rd row must be hidden.

HTML:

```
<div class="row au-grid-row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        ACTION
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        NAME
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        CUSTOMER ID (CDIF)
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       MOBILE NO.
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="x in customerList>
<div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="radio" class="badge-slider" name="customerInfo" id="custInfo">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{x.FullName}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{x.Customerid}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{x.Mobile}}
    </div>

</div>
<hr>
<div class="row text-center " ng-repeat="f in x.accountList" >
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="radio" name="accountInfo" id="accInfo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{f.accountNumber}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{f.accountType}}
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.customerList = [
            {
                "Customerid": "111111",
                "FullName": "CHINTAN MATHUKIA",
                "Mobile": "9999999999",
                "accountList": [{
                    "accountNumber": "131212121212121311",
                    "accountType": "Savings"
                },
                {
                    "accountNumber": "242525626262662622222",
                    "accountType": "Current"
                }],
            },
            {
                "Customerid": "222222",
                "FullName": "SMRITI SETHI",
                "Mobile": "9818842804",
                "accountList": [{
                    "accountNumber": "333333333333",
                    "accountType": "Savings"
                },
                {
                    "accountNumber": "444444444444",
                    "accountType": "Current"
                }],
            },
            {
                "Customerid": "3333333",
                "FullName": "GAUTAM RANA",
                "Mobile": "99999999999",
                "accountList": [{
                    "accountNumber": "4444444444444",
                    "accountType": "Savings"
                },
                {
                    "accountNumber": "4545454545454545",
                    "accountType": "Current"
                }],
            }
        ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to show/hide elements in **Angularjs** you can use `ng-show` directive with expression evaluating to `true` or `false`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.customerList = [{
      "Customerid": "111111",
      "FullName": "CHINTAN MATHUKIA",
      "Mobile": "9999999999",
      "accountList": [{
          "accountNumber": "131212121212121311",
          "accountType": "Savings"
        },
        {
          "accountNumber": "242525626262662622222",
          "accountType": "Current"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "Customerid": "222222",
      "FullName": "SMRITI SETHI",
      "Mobile": "9818842804",
      "accountList": [{
          "accountNumber": "333333333333",
          "accountType": "Savings"
        },
        {
          "accountNumber": "444444444444",
          "accountType": "Current"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "Customerid": "3333333",
      "FullName": "GAUTAM RANA",
      "Mobile": "99999999999",
      "accountList": [{
          "accountNumber": "4444444444444",
          "accountType": "Savings"
        },
        {
          "accountNumber": "4545454545454545",
          "accountType": "Current"
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row au-grid-row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      ACTION
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      NAME
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      CUSTOMER ID (CDIF)
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      MOBILE NO.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="x in customerList">
    <div class="row text-center">

      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="radio" class="badge-slider" name="customerInfo" id="custInfo" ng-value="x.Customerid" ng-model="$parent.selected">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{x.FullName}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{x.Customerid}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{x.Mobile}}
      </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row text-center " ng-repeat="f in x.accountList" ng-show="x.Customerid == $parent.selected" >
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="radio" name="accountInfo" id="accInfo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{f.accountNumber}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{f.accountType}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it is a bit incomplete. What I want here is - if I select Chintan's record then the rows with smriti and gautam should be hidden.

Comment: then move the `hide-show` logic to primary ng-repeat. that should do.

Comment: by the way if you selected chintan's record then how would you select smriti and gautam's record as they will be hidden?